# Load service from APK with android:exported=false

Tags: android, security, reflection, apk

I'm tying to load a Service from an APK, which is located at /system/app/LALA. The thing is, i'm getting the error below, because in the APP AndroidManifest, the Services has `android:exported = false`. Is there any way to load it?

> ### Code

```
String packagePath = "other.app.package";    
String apkName = null;
try {
    apkName = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packagePath, 0).sourceDir;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
PathClassLoader cLoader = new PathClassLoader(apkName, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
Context otherAppContext = createPackageContext(appPackage, CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY | CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE);    
String servicePath = packagePath + ".path.to.Service";
Class<?> Service = null;
try {
    Service = Class.forName(servicePath, true, cLoader);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}    
otherAppContext.startService(new Intent(otherAppContext, Service));
```

> ### Error
>
> *Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=other.app.package/.path.to.Service } without permission not exported from uid X*

[]'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to load it?

No, sorry. If the service is not exported, it can only be used internally by its own app.